# wxPython CheckListBox with HTML

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm using wxPython to create a GUI app. Right now I'm using a wx.CheckListBox to display options with check boxes, but I'd like the text in the CheckListBox to be formatted using HTML. What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `wxCheckListBox` with `wxHtmlWindow` and use `wxpTag` for the check boxes.

Here is some code to get you started.

```
import wx
import wx.lib.wxpTag


class HtmlCheckListBox(wx.html.HtmlWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent, choices=None):
        wx.html.HtmlWindow.__init__(self, parent)

        check_box = """
        <wxp module="wx" class="CheckBox">
            <param name="id" value="%d">
        </wxp>
        """

        self._ids = dict()

        if choices:
            items = list()
            for c, choice in enumerate(choices):
                i = wx.NewId()
                self._ids[i] = c
                items.append((check_box % i) + choice)
            self.SetPage("<hr>".join(items))

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX, self.OnCheck)

    def OnCheck(self, event):
        print "item:", self._ids[event.Id], "checked:", event.Checked()


class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        self.options = HtmlCheckListBox(
            self,
            [
                "<i>one</i>",
                "<b>two</b>",
                "<u>three</u>"
            ]
        )


app = wx.PySimpleApp()
app.TopWindow = TestFrame()
app.TopWindow.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```