# wxpython listbox newline in msw

Tags: python, windows, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm tring to add mutiline message to listbox using

```
wx.listbox.Append('part1 \r\n part2')
```

while on linux (gtk) im getting multiline box

on windows (msw) it just ignore the newline...

is there a way to get a similar functionality in windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The windows [ListBox control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775146%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) doesn't implement that behavior. While it allows drawing the item yourself and adjusting its height, wxWidgets doesn't expose this functionality for the ListBox.
As an alternative, you could use the [`wx.SimpleHtmlListBox`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.SimpleHtmlListBox-class.html) or derive from [`wx.HtmlListBox`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.HtmlListBox-class.html).

> **wxSimpleHtmlListBox** is an implementation of wxHtmlListBox which shows HTML content in the listbox rows.
>
> Unlike wxHtmlListBox, this is not an abstract class and thus it has the advantage that you can use it without deriving your own class from it. However, it also has the disadvantage that this is not a virtual control and thus it's not well-suited for those cases where you need to show a huge number of items: every time you add/insert a string, it will be stored internally and thus will take memory.

It inherits from the [`ItemContainer`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.ItemContainer-class.html) just like wx.ListBox, so the usage is essentially the same. Keep in mind that you have to escape certain characters (as shown in the example). For that you could use [`cgi.escape`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html#cgi.escape).

```
import wx
import cgi

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,None)
        lb = wx.SimpleHtmlListBox(self)
        lb.Append( cgi.escape("foo <&> bar") )
        lb.Append("<b>Line 1</b> <br> Line 2")
        
app = wx.PySimpleApp()
frame = MyFrame().Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Is there HtmlCheckListBox as well?

Comment: For check boxes you'd have to go a different way: [wxPython CheckListBox with HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037076/wxpython-checklistbox-with-html). But it won't be a ListBox anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it. The native widget probably doesn't support that behavior on Windows. You might be able to do it with the DVC_CustomRenderer though (new in the 2.9 series). I know you can do it with the UltimateListCtrl as the demo itself shows that. I would recommend going that route if it's a must-have feature.